# php exec() for ffmpeg not working

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, exec

hai i am using ffmpeg command in php exec() for converting any type of video to flv format the command i'm using i sworking fine in the command prompt but when i run the same commend it returns nothing..actully the output is Array( ) and the the third parameter $result is "1"

i've read similar questions like this on stackoverflow but it's not helping

most of the time i noticed that the issue is in path and the safe mode of php

and i have disabled safe mode using .htaccess the syntax is given below and i am using windows 7 os

the directory to the ffmpeg application is c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg

the full script and output is given below:

the ffmpeg command:

```
   ffmpeg -i c:\xampp\htdocs\video\original\robot.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -crf 17 c:\xampp\htdocs\video\vids\robot.flv
```

the php script:

```
 echo "starting ffmpeg...<br/>";

 echo exec("ffmpeg -i c:\xampp\htdocs\video\original\robot.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -crf 17 c:\xampp\htdocs\video\vids\robot.flv",$out,$r);
 var_dump($out);
 echo $r."<br/>";
 echo "done...<br/>";
 ?>
```

the htaccess for switching off the safe mode:

```
 php_value safe_mode "0"
```

the output:

```
 starting ffmpeg...
 array(0) { } 1 
 done...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one instead of using exec(ffmpeg -i 'inputfile' 'outputfile');

$cmd = "ffmpeg -i c:\xampp\htdocs\video\original\robot.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -crf 17 c:\xampp\htdocs\video\vids\robot.flv"

ob_start();

passthru($cmd);

$cmd_retr = ob_get_contents();

print_r($cmd_retr);

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo exec("cmd /c ffmpeg -i c:\\xampp\htdocs\video\original\robot.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 44100 -crf 17 c:\\xampp\htdocs\video\vids\robot.flv",$out,$r");
?>
```